# Html Agility Pack: how to parse a webresponse and get a specified html element in c#

Tags: c#, html, parsing, html-agility-pack

I googled my problem and found [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse `html` in `c#`. But there is no good examples and I can't use it to my purpose. I have a `html document` and it has a part like this:

```
<div class="pray-times-holder">
    <div class="pray-time">
        <div class="labels">
            Time1:</div>
        04:28:24
    </div>
    <div class="pray-time">
        <div class="labels">
            Time2:</div>
        06:04:41
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to get the value for `Time1` and `Time2`. e.g. `Time1` has value `04:28:24` and `Time2` has value `06:04:41` and I want to get these values. Can you help me please?

Comment: How familiar are you with the XmlDocument class and XPaths? The HAP has a very similar interface.

Comment: @Cameron no unfortunately i'm not familiar with xpath. can you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var results = doc.DocumentNode
    .Descendants("div")
    .Where(n => n.Attributes["class"] != null && n.Attributes["class"].Value == "pray-time")
    .Select(n => n.InnerText.Replace("\r\n","").Trim())
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

This console application code:

```
 HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
 doc.Load(yourHtml);
 foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class = 'labels']"))
 {
     Console.WriteLine(node.NextSibling.InnerText.Trim());
 }
```

will output this:

```
04:28:24
06:04:41
```